# Dealing with internet connectivity in different threads and separated classes

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm trying to use AsyncTask to run a background thread that accesses http over the internet.

The problem arises when I want to use a separated helper class to deal with http.

The reason I want to put this on a separated class is to have a cleaner compartmentalized code separating the UI functionality from the http functionality in different classes.
So I don't want to have anything related to http on the UI class, I just want to call this separated http helper class to deal with http.

So I'm confused on how to communicate back to the main thread (only for timing), since the AsyncTask method onPostExecute can actually access the UI, but I don't want the http helper class having to deal with the UI.
Should I use a public field in the http helper class and then have a loop in the main thread to chek on it for status?

Again, I want to have the UI stuff in one class, and the http stuff in a different class that only deals with http stuff.

What is the best way to communicate and accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The general way to do this is via a callback.  You define an interface with functions that should be called when an event occurs-  such as onHttpSuccess().  You make the UI class (probably your Activity) implement that interface.  You then pass an instance of that interface into your AsyncTask in the constructor.  Basically, you'd be moving doInBackground to another class, and doing all the real work of onPreExecute and onPostExecute in your constructor.

Your AsyncTask would look like (pseudocode):

```
class HttpTask extends AsyncTask{
    public interface HttpCallback{
        onHttpStart();
        onHttpSuccess();
        onHtpFail();
    }
    private HttpCallback mHttpCallback;
    public HttpTask(Context, HttpCallback cb){
        mHttpCallback = cb;
    }
    onPreExecute(){
        mHttpCallback.onHttpStart();
    }
    doInBackground(){
        //Do the HTTP transfer
    }
    onPostExecute(){
        mHttpCallback.onHttpSuccess();
    }
}
```

And your activity class

```
class MyActivity extends Activity implements HttpCallback{
    onHttpStart(){
        //Perform any start UI work
    }
    onHttpSuccess(){
        //Update the UI
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an interface/callback mechanism to achieve loose coupling.  Something like this:

Note - This is pseudo-code.  I have not compiled it.

1) Define a listener interface to receive notifications from your HTTP AsyncTask

```
public interface HttpListener {
    public void onHttpRequestCompleteUiThread(.....)
}
```

2) Require an instance of this interface in the constructor of your AsyncTask.

```
public class HttpTask extends AsyncTask {

    HttpListener listener;

    public HttpTask(HttpListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    ...
}
```

3) Callback into the listener in onPostExecute

```
 protected void onPostExecute(...) {
     listener. onHttpRequestCompleteUiThread(...
 }
```

4) In your activity (or fragment), implement the Listener interface.  In the onHttpRequestCompleteUiThread, you can then manipulate the UI.

This will provide clean separation of concerns.